# Raycast not hitting anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The raycast doesn't even give the `Debug.Log("it hit something` while the `Debug.DrawRay` does make a line between the enemy and the player.

The enemy who uses the following script is on the layer "Ignore Raycast" and the player it is trying to hit is on the "Default" layer.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector2 diff = PlayerMovement.playerTransform.position - transform.position;
    Ray raycastToPlayer = new Ray(transform.position, diff);
    Debug.Log(raycastToPlayer);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, diff, Color.white, 0.01f, true);
    if (Physics.Raycast(raycastToPlayer, out hit)) {
        Debug.Log("it hit something");
        if (hit.collider != null) {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Player"){
                float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to define a max distance for your `Physics.Raycast`

Comment: `Normalize` your `diff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Vector2` positions, so I assume your game is in 2D.  If so, I believe you need to use the 2D versions of the `Physics` classes (See [HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)):

```
void FixedUpdate() {

    Vector2 diff = (PlayerMovement.playerTransform.position - transform.position).Normalized;
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, diff);

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, diff, Color.white, 0.01f, true);

    if (hit.collider != null) {
        Debug.Log("Raycast hit: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);
        if (hit.transform.tag == "Player") {
            float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely missed that I was trying to use the 3d version of it instead of the 2d one. Silly mistake I've spent too long on

Answer (score 2):

For the Ray constructor you are using, the direction should be a Vector3:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html

But in your code you are passing a Vector2. If it is a 2D game you should use a different constructor:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray2D-ctor.html

Besides that, and as they have pointed you already in the comments, you will need to pass in Physics.Raycast the maxDistance parameter of the Ray:

- **ray**  The starting point and direction of the ray.
- **hitInfo**  If true is returned, hitInfo will contain more information
  about where the collider was hit. (See Also: RaycastHit).
- **maxDistance**  The max distance the ray should check for collisions.

And if you want to use layers, an extra paremeter will be required:

- **layerMask**    A Layer mask that is used to selectively ignore colliders
  when casting a ray.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html